# Angular NgRx Effect errors in Marble Testing: Expected $.length = 0 to equal 2. / Expected $[0] = undefined to equal Object

Tags: angular, rxjs, ngrx

I have an app that uses Angular and NgRx and I am having difficulties to test my Effect, using Marble Testing.

The error that I get is:

```
Expected $.length = 0 to equal 2.
Expected $[0] = undefined to equal Object({ frame: 10, notification: Notification({ kind: 'N', value: LoadOrderLogisticStatusSuccess({ payload: Object({ 1047522: Object({ status: 0, partner: Object({ id: 1, slug: 'loggi' }), eta: '2020-06-09 10:00', pickupEta: '2020-06-09 12:00' }) }), type: 'load-order-logistic-status-success' }), error: undefined, hasValue: true }) }).
Expected $[1] = undefined to equal Object({ frame: 20, notification: Notification({ kind: 'C', value: undefined, error: undefined, hasValue: false }) }).
```

Here is the Effect:

```js
@Injectable()
export class OrderLogisticStatusEffects {
  loadOrdersLogisticStatus$ = createEffect(() =>
    this.actions$.pipe(
      ofType(LOAD_ORDERS_LOGISTIC_STATUS),
      withLatestFrom(this.store$.pipe(select(orderLogisticsStatusPollingIntervalSelector))),
      switchMap(([action, pollingInterval]) =>
        timer(0, pollingInterval).pipe(
          withLatestFrom(this.store$.pipe(select(selectedCompanySelector))),
          switchMap(([timerNum, company]) => this.loadOrdersLogisticStatus(pollingInterval, company))
        )
      )
    )
  );

  constructor(private actions$: Actions, private orderLogisticStatusService: OrderLogisticStatusService, private store$: Store<AppState>) {}

  private loadOrdersLogisticStatus(
    pollingInterval: number,
    company: Company
  ): Observable<LoadOrderLogisticStatusSuccess | LoadOrderLogisticStatusFail> {
    if (!company?.logisticsToken) {
      return of(new LoadOrderLogisticStatusFail(new Error('No company selected')));
    }

    this.orderLogisticStatusService.getOrdersStatus(company.logisticsToken).pipe(
      timeout(pollingInterval),
      map((result) => new LoadOrderLogisticStatusSuccess(result)),
      catchError((error) => {
        if (error.name === 'TimeoutError') {
          console.warn('Timeout error while loadin logistic status service', error);
        } else {
          console.error('Error loading order logistic status', error);
          Sentry.captureException(error);
        }

        return of(new LoadOrderLogisticStatusFail(error));
      })
    );
  }
}
```

And here is my test:

```js
fdescribe('Order Logistic Status Effect', () => {
  let actions$: Observable<Action>;
  let effects: OrderLogisticStatusEffects;

  describe('With a selected company', () => {
    beforeEach(() => {
      const mockState = {
        ordersLogisticStatus: {
          pollingInterval: 10,
        },
        company: {
          selectedCompany: {
            logisticsToken: 'ey.xxxx.yyyy',
          },
        },
      };

      TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        providers: [
          { provide: OrderLogisticStatusService, useValue: jasmine.createSpyObj('orderLogisticsStatusServiceSpy', ['getOrdersStatus']) },
          OrderLogisticStatusEffects,
          provideMockActions(() => actions$),
          provideMockStore({
            selectors: [
              {
                selector: orderLogisticsStatusPollingIntervalSelector,
                value: 30,
              },
              {
                selector: selectedCompanySelector,
                value: {
                  logisticsToken: 'ey.xxxx.yyy',
                },
              },
            ],
          }),
        ],
      });

      effects = TestBed.inject<OrderLogisticStatusEffects>(OrderLogisticStatusEffects);
    });

    it('should sucessfully load the orders logistics status', () => {
      const service: jasmine.SpyObj<OrderLogisticStatusService> = TestBed.inject(OrderLogisticStatusService) as any;
      service.getOrdersStatus.and.returnValue(cold('-a|', { a: mockData }));

      actions$ = hot('a', { a: new LoadOrdersLogisticStatus() });
      const expected = hot('-a|', {
        a: new LoadOrderLogisticStatusSuccess(mockData),
      });

      getTestScheduler().flush();
      expect(effects.loadOrdersLogisticStatus$).toBeObservable(expected);
    });
  });
});

const mockData = {
  1047522: {
    status: 0,
    partner: {
      id: 1,
    },
    eta: '2020-06-09 10:00',
    pickupEta: '2020-06-09 12:00',
  },
};
```

The problem seems to be happening with my service mock. Even though I configured it to return a cold observable, it seems that it is returning undefined.

Can anyone help me?

**Stack Blitz**: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-effects-test

Comment: I think the problem is that `actions$` is initialized **after** your effects class injects it, so it would get the old value. Try to set `actions$ = hot('a',...)` before `effects = TestBed.inject...`

Comment: Hi, I don't think that this is the case, because my effect is being called. The problem is happening in my service mock. Somehow the mocked function is returning undefined instead of the cold observer.

Comment: ‘$.length = 0 to equal 2’ makes me think that actions$ didn’t emit at all. I might be wrong. Could you create a stackblitz?

Comment: Yes, I've update the description with this stackblitz link: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-effects-test.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-effects-test-ysv63a?file=src/effects/order-logistic-status.spec.ts).

---

There were a few problems:

Firstly, the `loadOrdersLogisticStatus` was missing a return:

```js
loadOrdersLogisticStatus (/* ... */) {
  return this.orderLogisticStatusService.getOrdersStatus(/* ... */)
}
```

Then, I found out that `jasmine-marbles` does not set the `AsyncScheduler.delegate` automatically, as opposed to [`TestScheduler.run`](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/internal/testing/TestScheduler.ts#L403-L430):

```js
 run<T>(callback: (helpers: RunHelpers) => T): T {
  const prevFrameTimeFactor = TestScheduler.frameTimeFactor;
  const prevMaxFrames = this.maxFrames;

  TestScheduler.frameTimeFactor = 1;
  this.maxFrames = Infinity;
  this.runMode = true;
  AsyncScheduler.delegate = this;

  /* ... */
}
```

This is important because when using marbles, everything is **synchronous**. But in your implementation, there was a `timer(0, pollingInterval)` observable, which, by default, uses `AsyncScheduler`. Without setting `AsyncScheduler.delegate`, we'd be having asynchronous actions, which I think it was the main problem.

So, in order to set the `delegate` property, I've added this line in `beforeEach()`:

```js
AsyncScheduler.delegate = getTestScheduler();
```

Finally, I think there was a small problem with your assertions. Your effect property does not seem to ever complete, and you're also using `timer(0, pollingInterval)`. So what I think you could do now is to add the `take(N)` operator in order to test against `N` emissions:

```js
it("should sucessfully load the orders logistics status", () => {
  const service: jasmine.SpyObj<OrderLogisticStatusService> = TestBed.inject(OrderLogisticStatusService) as any;
  service.getOrdersStatus.and.callFake(() => cold('-a|', { a: mockData }));

  actions$ = hot('a', { a: new LoadOrdersLogisticStatus() });
  const expected = hot('-a--(b|)', {
    a: new LoadOrderLogisticStatusSuccess(mockData),
    b: new LoadOrderLogisticStatusSuccess(mockData),
  });

  expect(effects.loadOrdersLogisticStatus$.pipe(take(2))).toBeObservable(expected);
});
```

`'-a--(b|)'` - `a` is sent at the 10th frame, and `b` + `complete` notification(due to `take`) are sent at `40th` frame, because the `pollingInterval` is `30` and the current frame would be `10` when the second notification(`b`) would be scheduled.

Comment: Hi Andrei, thank you for all the help. In the end I had to do some tweaks to your answer to get everything working. If you would like to update it, I will be more than happy to mark it as this question's answer.

Comment: The custom event params that I've added below: `createEffect(() => ({ scheduler = asyncScheduler, stopTimer = EMPTY } = {})`, and their calls on the test.

Comment: Okay, but that was your solution, not mine :). I’m glad that you worked it out. However, I’m pretty sure you can apply the same approach to your real case. Did it not work this way? : “AsyncScheduler.delegate = getTestScheduler()”. Also, I’d say the second ‘problem’ is something expected as it’s the same as if you had a setInterval(i.e timer with second arg), except that everting happens synchronously.

Comment: I just wanted to give you more credit for the help, since I would never thought of looking into the scheduler itself if it wasn't for you. ;)

Comment: Using this: `AsyncScheduler.delegate = getTestScheduler()` did work inside the Stackblitz, but it didn't work on my actual project. I think it is because the `AsyncScheduler` is somewere deep inside rxjs and the change got overwritten somewhere else. Passing the scheduler directly into the effect is what did the trick.

Comment: Thanks! You can accept this answer as is if you want, I wouldn't want to modify that way since that solution can be already found in your answer. Anyway, it's important that we found the problem & a solution for it.

Comment: Done! Thank you again for the help!

Comment: It was my pleasure to help. Thanks! Good luck

Answer (score 0):

Andrei's solution did work for the Stack Blitz, but it didn't work in my own environment, I think it is because of some import mix up. But the idea behind it: that the `TestScheduler` for the `jasmine-marbles` does not replace the `AsyncScheduler` for the RxJs is correct. And this was my problem (besides forgetting to add a `return`statement in the `loadOrdersLogisticStatus` function).

So to make everything work I had to do two things:

First I had to manually set the effect's scheduler as the `TestScheduler`. When I did this, I was finally able to see that the `timer` observable was emitting results and not `undefined` as before.

However I then had another problem. The `timer` wouldn't stop emitting, so I got a long error stream like this:

```
Expected $.length = 26 to equal 2.
Unexpected $[2] = Object({ frame: 60, notification: Notification({ kind: 'N', value: LoadOrderLogisticStatusSuccess({ payload: Object({ 1047522: Object({ status: 0, partner: Object({ id: 1, slug: 'loggi' }), eta: '2020-06-09 10:00', pickupEta: '2020-06-09 12:00' }) }), type: 'load-order-logistic-status-success' }), error: undefined, hasValue: true }) }) in array.
Unexpected $[3] = Object({ frame: 90, notification: Notification({ kind: 'N', value: LoadOrderLogisticStatusSuccess({ payload: Object({ 1047522: Object({ status: 0, partner: Object({ id: 1, slug: 'loggi' }), eta: '2020-06-09 10:00', pickupEta: '2020-06-09 12:00' }) }), type: 'load-order-logistic-status-success' }), error: undefined, hasValue: true }) }) in array.
Unexpected $[4] = Object({ frame: 120, notification: Notification({ kind: 'N', value: LoadOrderLogisticStatusSuccess({ payload: Object({ 1047522: Object({ status: 0, partner: Object({ id: 1, slug: 'loggi' }), eta: '2020-06-09 10:00', pickupEta: '2020-06-09 12:00' }) }), type: 'load-order-logistic-status-success' }), error: undefined, hasValue: true }) }) in array.
Unexpected $[5] = Object({ frame: 150, notification: Notification({ kind: 'N', value: LoadOrderLogisticStatusSuccess({ payload: Object({ 1047522: Object({ status: 0, partner: Object({ id: 1, slug: 'loggi' }), eta: '2020-06-09 10:00', pickupEta: '2020-06-09 12:00' }) }), type: 'load-order-logistic-status-success' }), error: undefined, hasValue: true }) }) in array.
Unexpected $[6] = Object({ frame: 180, notification: Notification({ kind: 'N', value: LoadOrderLogisticStatusSuccess({ payload: Object({ 1047522: Object({ status: 0, partner: Object({ id: 1, slug: 'loggi' }), eta: '2020-06-09 10:00', pickupEta: '2020-06-09 12:00' }) }), type: 'load-order-logistic-status-success' }), error: undefined, hasValue: true }) }) in array.
Unexpected $[7] = Object({ frame: 210, notification: Notification({ kind: 'N', value: LoadOrderLogisticStatusSuccess({ payload: Object({ 1047522: Object({ status: 0, partner: Object({ id: 1, slug: 'loggi' }), eta: '2020-06-09 10:00', pickupEta: '2020-06-09 12:00' }) }), type: 'load-order-logistic-status-success' }), error: undefined, hasValue: true }) }) in array.
Unexpected $[8] = Object({ frame: 240, notification: Notification({ kind: 'N', value: LoadOrderLogisticStatusSuccess({ payload: Object({ 1047522: Object({ status: 0, partner: Object({ id: 1, slug: 'loggi' }), eta: '2020-06-09 10:00', pickupEta: '2020-06-09 12:00' }) }), type: 'load-order-logistic-status-success' }), error: undefined, hasValue: true }) }) in array.
Unexpected $[9] = Object({ frame: 270, notification: Notification({ kind: 'N', value: LoadOrderLogisticStatusSuccess({ payload: Object({ 1047522: Object({ status: 0, partner: Object({ id: 1, slug: 'loggi' }), eta: '2020-06-09 10:00', pickupEta: '2020-06-09 12:00' }) }), type: 'load-order-logistic-status-success' }), error: undefined, hasValue: true }) }) in array.
```

The first two values were ok, but the other ones weren't. So the second thing I did was use a `takeUntil` operator to unsubscribe from the `timer` one the test was done (I am not sure if this was the best way to do it, because I must never use this operator outside of the test, otherwise my polling will stop).

Here is the final working version of the code:

Effect:

```js
@Injectable()
export class OrderLogisticStatusEffects {
  loadOrdersLogisticStatus$ = createEffect(() => ({ scheduler = asyncScheduler, stopTimer = EMPTY } = {}) =>
    this.actions$.pipe(
      ofType(LOAD_ORDERS_LOGISTIC_STATUS),
      withLatestFrom(this.store$.pipe(select(orderLogisticsStatusPollingIntervalSelector))),
      switchMap(([action, pollingInterval]) =>
        timer(0, pollingInterval, scheduler).pipe(
          takeUntil(stopTimer),
          withLatestFrom(this.store$.pipe(select(selectedCompanySelector))),
          switchMap(([timerNum, company]) => this.loadOrdersLogisticStatus(pollingInterval, company))
        )
      )
    )
  );

  constructor(private actions$: Actions, private orderLogisticStatusService: OrderLogisticStatusService, private store$: Store<AppState>) {}

  private loadOrdersLogisticStatus(
    pollingInterval: number,
    company: Company
  ): Observable<LoadOrderLogisticStatusSuccess | LoadOrderLogisticStatusFail> {
    if (!company?.logisticsToken) {
      return of(new LoadOrderLogisticStatusFail(new Error('No company selected')));
    }

    return this.orderLogisticStatusService.getOrdersStatus(company.logisticsToken).pipe(
      timeout(pollingInterval),
      map((result) => new LoadOrderLogisticStatusSuccess(result)),
      catchError((error) => {
        if (error.name === 'TimeoutError') {
          console.warn('Timeout error while loadin logistic status service', error);
        } else {
          console.error('Error loading order logistic status', error);
          Sentry.captureException(error);
        }

        return of(new LoadOrderLogisticStatusFail(error));
      })
    );
  }
}
```

Test:

```js
fdescribe('Order Logistic Status Effect', () => {
  let actions$: Observable<Action>;
  let effects: OrderLogisticStatusEffects;

  describe('With a selected company', () => {
    beforeEach(() => {
      TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        providers: [
          { provide: OrderLogisticStatusService, useValue: jasmine.createSpyObj('orderLogisticsStatusServiceSpy', ['getOrdersStatus']) },
          OrderLogisticStatusEffects,
          provideMockActions(() => actions$),
          provideMockStore({
            selectors: [
              {
                selector: orderLogisticsStatusPollingIntervalSelector,
                value: 30,
              },
              {
                selector: selectedCompanySelector,
                value: {
                  logisticsToken: 'ey.xxxx.yyy',
                },
              },
            ],
          }),
        ],
      });

      effects = TestBed.inject<OrderLogisticStatusEffects>(OrderLogisticStatusEffects);
    });

    it('should sucessfully load the orders logistics status', () => {
      const service = TestBed.inject(OrderLogisticStatusService) as jasmine.SpyObj<OrderLogisticStatusService>;
      service.getOrdersStatus.and.callFake(() => cold('a|', { a: mockData }));

      actions$ = hot('a', { a: new LoadOrdersLogisticStatus() });
      const expected = hot('a--b', {
        a: new LoadOrderLogisticStatusSuccess(mockData),
        b: new LoadOrderLogisticStatusSuccess(mockData),
      });

      const stopTimer = hot('----a', { a: 'stop' });

      const testScheduler = getTestScheduler();
      expect(effects.loadOrdersLogisticStatus$({ scheduler: testScheduler, stopTimer })).toBeObservable(expected);
    });
  });
});

const mockData = {
  1047522: {
    status: 0,
    partner: {
      id: 1,
      slug: 'loggi',
    },
    eta: '2020-06-09 10:00',
    pickupEta: '2020-06-09 12:00',
  },
};
```